# PyQt4 - Maximize window along with inside widgets

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a main window and I want that when I maximize it the widgets inside it should automatically be resized ....

Is there any way I can do that ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use layout objects (such as `QHBoxLayout` or `QGridLayout`) to organize your widgets inside, and set the widgets' resize modes accordingly. Note that standard Qt-supplied widgets support resizing by default.

Comment: how do you set the widgets' resize modes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save you a lot of work, don't hand-code the ui. Use Qt Creator to create a ui file and then load this file dynamically using PyQt4.uic module. There is also a "static" approach that generates python code from Qt Creator ui files.

Comment: did you mean Qt Designer?